# how to select which browser to open by sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I've set  " chrome " to be a default browser . In some case , I have to preview a code with firefox, 
but for sublime text 3 , once choose " open in browser , the default browser will call.
Would it be possible to setup the sublime text 3 to open the others browser preview ( firefox )instead of the default browser ?

Comment: https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser ?

Comment: yes it is , thank you Mathletics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sublime Text - View In Browser](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser)

Have a look here:

**Sublime Text - View In Browser**

View In Browser is a Sublime Text plugin that will open whatever is in your current view/tab. If the file current open is new and has not been saved a temporary file is created (in your default temp directory for your OS) with the extension of .htm and your browser will open it. However if the current open file is saved and has a name this plugin will open it in whatever you have set to handle its type.

By default the keystroke assigned to this plugin is CTRL + ALT + V.